# How to backup mist wallets?

Tags: accounts, wallets, addresses, keystore, backup

I know I can [backup the keystore](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108/87) files from my running ethereum client which holds my accounts.

But how can I backup wallets created with mist? Is it enough to write down the public address where the wallet contract is stored?

Comment: There are no json files in keystore folder for my wallet contracts. So there must be another way to backup contract wallets. I also don't understand this comment above: 'You could also manually add the wallet contracts back at any time."

Comment: They do not have the .json extension, they are still JSON files. Every file inside your keystore folder is a keystore file. They should all start with `UTC-2016-4-5--<address>`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

#### How to Access the Files to Back Up

Using Mist - Backup Accounts

Go to the top bar and select `ACCOUNTS` -> `BACKUP` -> `ACCOUNTS`.

This will open a folder. Inside this folder there are keystrore files that have long names starting with `UTC--2016-04-14.......` Each of these files represent an account. Back up these up.

Using Mist - Backup Wallet Contracts

Go to the top bar and go `ACCOUNTS` -> `BACKUP` -> `APPLICATION DATA`. This will open a folder. As far as I can tell, just back up this entire folder.

You could also manually add the wallet contracts back at any time, obviously, but this is easier and more convenient.

---

#### How to actually back up

You want to store the keystore files in multiple locations & multiple physical locations. Keep in mind, you must prevent loss of both the **keystore file** and **password** due to loss or failure of you hard drive, USB drive, or whatever method you are using to back up. You also must keep in mind physical loss / damage of an entire area (think fire or flood).

For example, consider the add'l security of storing things in 3 places, over 1:
- On computer

- On a USB drive in apartment.
- On a USB or paper at a trusted family member's house (e.g. with things like your birth certificate)

This way if your house burns down, you still have access to your funds. If your HDD crashes, your still access.

If you do want a paper option, you can import your Mist keystore file into MyEtherWallet (running offline/locally, see [#5 here](https://myetherwallet.groovehq.com/knowledge_base/topics/how-do-i-run-myetherwallet-dot-com-offline-slash-locally)). Follow those instructions and use the [View Wallet Info](https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info) tab in order to access your Mist wallet and then print a paper version.

---

#### Using old Mist without the `ACCOUNTS` -> `BACKUP` available.

On some versions, (0.3.9) there may just be a BACKUP option in the top bar, not under accounts. For old versions (0.3.7 or lower) the backup option is simply not there.

Depending on what OS you have, you need to navigate to the right folder (below) and back these keystore files / the entire keystore folder up.

**Accounts**

- Mac: `~/Library/Ethereum/keystore`
- Linux: `~/.ethereum/keystore`
- Windows: `%APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore`

**Wallet Contracts**

The above will only back up your normal accounts. Wallet Contracts can be manually re-added, or you can back up the data folder. As far as I can tell:

- Mac: `~/Library/Application Support/Mist/`
- Linux: `~/.config/Mist`  or, in earlier versions: `~/.config/Chromium/Mist` (folder is hidden)
- Windows: `C:\Users\< Your Username >\AppData\Roaming` -or- `~\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore`

The folders I see online tend to be all over the place. I can confirm that the above certainly hold true to my Mac.

---

#### And once again: Back up your KEYSTORE FILES (aka your private key) and your PASSWORDS. Both items are necessary to access your account. Your address (public key) is not actually needed to restore access.

--

Edit: [I found this (possibly out of date) list for go (geth) and c++ (eth) clients](https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/2114/where-are-my-config-files-go-and-cpp) which may be helpful for some.

Comment: This answer has already bolded the need to backup **passwords** too, but emphasizing it again for safety.

Comment: ACCOUNTS -> BACKUP -> ACCOUNTS doesn't do anything for me.  Any thoughts?  Windows 10, Ethereum Wallet v0.8.10

Comment: Then just check up `%APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore` directory.

Comment: Out of curiosity, the answer from Andreas below mentions backing up `Application Data` - is this necessary? Is the keystore + password alone enough to recover a wallet, for example were my HDD to fail?

Answer (score 9):

If you use the latest version of the Mist wallet 0.3.9, then you can 
backup your wallet with saving the AppData. You can do that by clicking
on Backup in the Menu bar and click "Backup App Data" which points you 
to the installation directory where your wallet is saved. In my case it is 
located here "C:\Users\Andreas\AppData\Roaming" on Windows 10 - 64 Bit.

[image: Mist Wallet Scrrenshot]

Just copy the whole "Mist" Folder to a secure location to have a backup. 
In my case it has just about 6.4MB.

Now you have a backup. I cannot say if the same is true for Mac and Linux.

Greetings from Austria

Andreas

Comment: That's enough to secure my funds? I can't see any private keys in that directory.

Comment: In my case it worked. I just renamed the Mist folder for test. Then started again the wallet. Then you dont see your wallets. and a new Mist folder gets generated. If you then delete the new Mist folder and rename the first folder back to "Mist" then everything is displayed again. Your wallet and the amount. I´m not sure in which exact file or files these informations are stored. So i simply copy and backup the whole folder. But it would be interesting in which files it is saved.

Comment: Because it is a contract wallet i guess the amount of ether is just stored in the contract and not in a file. You can import the wallet later by just typing in your wallet adress. So you should also backup this adress.

Comment: That's maybe because mist does require a client in the back who handles the private keys.

Comment: in Linux it's ~/.config/Mist right?

Comment: Do I have to encrypt the AppData contents before storing it in Dropbox or email, or is it already in a password-protected format?

Comment: @5chdn There seems to be quite a bit of confusion about what to backup from Ethereum Wallet. There are two folders. One is your keystore (Accounts), and the other is the "Backup App Data" which stores pointers to contracts. Obviously the keystore directory is way more important. The "Backup App Data" is a bit of an annoyance if you lose it because you'll have to comb through transactions to figure out what contracts you had.

Comment: But how do you restore this? A backup without a restore option is a bit weird.

Answer (score 7):

## Backup

To backup your accounts from Ethereum Wallet, see  [How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets).

The files that you need to backup will have names like the following:

```
user@Kumquat:~/.ethereum/keystore$ ls
UTC--2016-04-17T01-23-45.279405976Z--aaaaab3ad17cd9aca6fd5343a53a513685c7aaaa
UTC--2016-04-17T02-34-56.029466208Z--bbbb8622d70f62f212aef64e7e26e4746dc8bbbb
UTC--2016-04-22T03-45-01.402684763Z--cccc5fc7979143c593c6c01eae6d22b7d6eecccc
```

## Restore

To restore these accounts, copy these files back to your Ethereum keystore directory. The location of your keystore directory depends on your operating system - here are the directories:

- Mac: ~/Library/Ethereum/keystore
- Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
- Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum/keystore

Comment: Please note, I moved this answer.

Comment: Seems to be out of date