# Which wallet am I using?

Tags: wallets

Long story short, I got into ether mining back in '16, even went as far to buy some ethers and sent it to... wherever? I stopped in Dec '16 and forgot all about it, packed up and stored the PC while I traveled. I finally got a new place and booted up the PC, showing my ether info in etherscan.io - I can login and definitely know the password, however I cannot send what I have because etherscan.io is not a wallet... cannot remember where it is, but I DO have my address. cpp-ethereum is still set up on this win 10 machine, and I opened geth up and inquired to my balance - it said 0! even though etherscan.io shows my actual balance! how do I access my funds and transfer it to coinbase?

Thanks!
- J

Comment: There was a hard fork last year, so likely your cpp-ethereum is no updated and likely in the wrong fork. To access your funds likely you will have to search for a UTC or JSON file that contains your private key without that you will not be able to access the ether.

Comment: Perhaps this answer may works as a guide where to search on linux https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/1627/mist-wallet-balance-not-showing/3203#3203

Comment: Ismael - I'm using a windows machine, and I can find my keystore. Nicolas is right, it's a possible duplicate of the link he provided, with some exception.

Comment: Nicolas Massart - I ran geth --fast just now and right now it says geth is opposed to the hard fork. I can change my choice prior to 1920000 block, and im currently on 1741146, fast syncing is disabled. last thing it reads is: IPC endpoint opened: \\.\pipe\geth.ipc

Comment: You should run the more recent version of geth v1.7.3. With `geth account list` you get a listing of your wallets, like `Account #0: {b362..} keystore://C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Roaming\Ethereum\keystore\UTC--2015-03-02T12-27-53.183713820Z--b362..`. The `UTC...` is your wallet file and you can use that with MyEtherWallet to access your funds without synchorinizing.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is your private key to transfer the tokens. Have you already checked, whether your funds are on another account? You should be able to check with '''geth account list''' [see this link](http://ethdocs.org/en/latest/account-management.html). The link also provides details on importing private key and backups. Did you do a offline backup of your keystore?

As you already mentioned, Etherscan.io is not a wallet, therefore the private key won't be stored there, so I don't think you'll have much luck there.

Comment: yes, it shows my account. no problem. matches with what etherscan.io has. just, i dont know where that account is.i don't think i did an offline backup either.