# Ethereum wallet doesn't sync v. 0.7.3 stuck or too slow using Os x 10.9.5

Tags: wallets, synchronization, mac-osx

I'm using Ethereum 0.7.3 and it doesn't sync on my MacPro Os x 10.9.5. It is too slow or it get's suck. I tried v.0.7.1 and v.0.7.2, and it's the same problem.

My Internet connection it's ok, I disabled the firewall just in case. But still doens't work.

I would like to solve this without using geth, as I'm not familiar with terminal console.

Do you have any suggestion for this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use geth right now. Otherwise you can wait for the next version of Mist which will bundle geth 1.4. It's actually pretty simple to install geth and run from the console window. It's your best solution if you need to use mist on a Mac right now.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have any accounts, make a backup of your keystore files. [Instructions](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets)
2. Install geth by opening up your command prompt or terminal and pasting the following and then hit enter: `bash <(curl -L https://install-geth.ethereum.org)`
3. When it is done installing, type `geth removedb` and hit enter.*
4. Then type `geth --fast` and hit enter.
5. Wait for it to sync. It should take a few hours.
6. Then open the Ethereum Wallet app.

* `geth removedb` will remove all chaindata and let you start fresh. If you for some reason want to keep this in case this new method doesn't work, you can navigate to your keystore folder, move up one level to see the `chaindata` folder, and move that folder to another location. If syncing fast doesn't work and you want to continue where you left off, simply more your chaindata folder back to it's original spot, replacing the new folder.

---

- [Mist Releases](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases)
- [Geth Installation Instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Building-Ethereum)