# How to I import my Ethereum wallet into MyEtherWallet

Tags: tokens

I have an Ethereum Wallet on my Companys Laptop. Unfortunately I have to give it back. I also bought Tokens from the DAO with that account. How can I transfer / access my wallet on a different device. How can I access this account from Ethereum Wallet using MyEtherWallet? I'm not a great coder, so ... I'm afraid too loose my (Tokens)...

Comment: For first question on transferring Ethereum Wallet: http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets

Answer (score 5):

1. [Back up your keystore folder onto a USB drive or 2.](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets)
2. Go to MyEtherWallet.com and make sure you can access that wallet using the http://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info
3. Delete everything from the original computer.
4. Install Mist on a new computer, or use MyEtherWallet moving forward.

Comment: Do not use HTTP please correct the url and use HTTPS

Comment: But yo didn't mentioned how to import to MyEtherWallet using that info :(