# How to upgrade geth and mist in Ubuntu?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ubuntu, upgrading

I set up a Ubuntu laptop specifically to install Geth/Mist 0.5.2 and have not upgraded since. I want to upgrade to 0.8.1 but need some direction. Am happy to work from terminal, but don't have enough background to do this on my own.

I have searched reddit and StackExchange but haven't seen an upgrade walk through for absolute beginners. I have downloaded Ethereum-Wallet-linux64-0-8-1.zip from https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases but don't know if I just need to open the wallet icon to update or work from the command line. I have ether in my wallet that I don't want to lose. My keys are backed up. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Upgrading Mist on Ubuntu

1. Backup your keystore (`/.ethereum/keystore`)
2. Backup your data folder (`/.config/Mist`)
3. Download the latest zip from [here](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases) and install.

For more information on backing up wallets, see here: [How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets)

## Upgrading `go-ethereum`:

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:ethereum/ethereum-dev
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

**or** simply build the git repository.

```
git clone https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum
cd go-ethereum  # (use "git checkout <branch>" to switch to branches or tag/commit. ex: git checkout -f tags/v1.10.16)
make geth       # (to build geth binary in build/bin)
make clean      # (clean things up, if you want to build a different branch or commit)
sudo cp build/bin/geth /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you expand on step 3 of "upgrading Mist on Ubuntu" I have downloaded the latest zip and extracted it. My older version of Mist is in now in the same directory as the new one. Do I just open the folder and click the purple "Ethereum Wallet" icon or does "install" require more steps?

Comment: Just downloading the new version and running it is enough. Your accounts and other data are abstracted from the wallet executable in the system.

Answer (score 1):

As an extra  to previous answer

Mist update (if Mist is installed in /home/mist)

```
mv mist mist_old_version
wget https://github.com/ethereum/mist/releases/download/0.8.1/Mist-linux64-0-8-1.zip
unzip Mist-linux64-0-8-1.zip
mv Mist-linux64-0-8-1 mist
```

Only thing you should avoid to keep your ether safe - never run old versions geth/Mist if you`ve already started to use a new one on the same user account.

Comment: You should also check `sha256sum`. And did you notice you installed the `EthereumWallet` not `Mist`?