# Can not get a value by calling method from another Contract

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain

I have created two Contract to separate out storage and validation rules.

**ValidationService.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;
import "./Storage.sol";

contract ValidationService {

Storage public store;


 constructor(address add) public{
    store=Storage(add);
 }


 function getMyNumber() public constant returns (uint) {

     return store.getNumber();

 }


}
```

**Storage.sol**

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.16;

contract Storage {

uint public mynum = 5;


  function getNumber() public constant returns (uint) {
    return mynum;
  }

 }
```

I have called getMyNumber method which called getNumber method of Storage contract and it should return 5 as a output.

```
validationservice.getMyNumber.call()
```

The above code is working fine in remix and truffle development environment but it is not working in private blockhain network using Geth.

If i call getNumber method of Storage contract directly from geth console, It's working fine.

Can anyone please guide where is my mistake

Comment: I have found the error in the miner console, after enable verbosity option. Ethereum threw "Invalid opcode 0x3d" error message whenever, I call getMyNumber Method. Please help me if anyone know about this error and how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

I have resolved the issue. I have used **"byzantiumBlock": 0** into genesis.json file and recreated private blockchain.

For more detail, please refer

[Invalid opcode 0x3d](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/46725/invalid-opcode-0x3d)

Thanks you all

Answer (score 0):

This works fine. The only case in which it won't work is if you are not passing the correct address when deploying `validationService`.

Hope this helps

Comment: I am passing the correct address. The method has been executed successfully without any error but  always returns 0 instead of 5.

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting below error-

```
call to ValidationService.getMyNumber errored: VM error: revert.
revert  The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The constructor should be payable if you send value. Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

then you are using the incorrect address. It would be great if you can share some more information about the error you are facing.

Comment: Method is executed successfully without any error. It returns 0 instead of 5 on Geth console.

Comment: I ran miner using Verbosity level 5 and I have found that, It gave "Invalid opcode 0x3d" error message whenever, I call getMyNumber Method. Please guide me what this error is and how to solve it