# Problem with ETH withdrawal from DAO

Tags: mist, the-dao

I have some problems with Mist and with withdrawing my ETH from The DAO. For my financial condition it is significant value of money and I would really appreciate your help here. I was about to execute the procedure of approving transfer from the DAO to the DAO Withdrawal through mist. I was using this instruction: [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft/7205#7205) In point 3, after I have set all the data to execute "Approve", I have realised that I have might done some mistake putting numbers so I have stopped right there and I had deleted the contract before executing "Approve", hoping it would reset all data I have put so far and I could start from the beginning. When I have added The DAO contract to watch once again, it's balance was showing "0" and I could not see the contract menu , also my dao token preview in Mist was showing "0". I m afraid I could have lost all ETH. Is this possible to repair this situation and withdraw my eth properly? Is there something that can be done? Please help me!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some steps to check/do:

1. Check that your account DAO balance is non-zero by entering your address into [daohub.org](https://daohub.org/), click Check Your Balance, enter your address and click Check.
2. Restart Ethereum Wallet and check your The DAO contract balance function again.
3. If 2. does not work, remove The DAO contract by clicking on the contract and click the garbage bin icon and type in the confirmation text. Then set up The DAO contract again using the link https://daowiki.atlassian.net/wiki/display/DAO/How+to+add+and+watch+the+DAO+contract .
4. Check your The DAO contract balance function again.
5. Post your response to the above and we can work out what to do next.

**Update after your first comment below**

1. Check your Mist version

   The menu Ethereum Wallet -> About Ethereum Wallet should show Version 0.8.1
2. Check that you are on Mainnet

   The top bar of your Mist browser should not show PRIVATE-NET or TESTNET. The menu Develop -> Network should show a tick next to Main Network.
3. Check that you are on the hard-forked blockchain

   The menu Develop -> "The DAO" Fork should show a tick next to Support DAO Fork.
4. Check that your blockchain in Mist is in sync

   Check what the number is in the middle of the top bar in Mist. This should show a block number greater than 1,926,463.
5. Remove your The DAO contract by clicking on the contract and click the garbage bin icon and type in the confirmation text. Exit Mist. Start Mist.

   Then use the screen printed step-by-step guide to set up The DAO contract again. [How to use the Withdraw Contract with Mist](https://blog.slock.it/how-to-use-the-withdraw-contract-with-mist-de5d85a981c9#.pg4sqbgna)
6. Check again. If it still does not work, you may just have to use Method 1 - MyEtherWallet in [How do I convert my The DAO tokens into ethers using the withdrawal contract after the hard fork?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7204/how-do-i-convert-my-the-dao-tokens-into-ethers-using-the-withdrawal-contract-aft).

   You can find your keystore file from the location listed in [How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1981/1268).
7. You may want to try resetting your Mist data. In Linux, you can do this by renaming ~/.config/Mist to another name, for example:

   ```
   cd ~/.config
   mv Mist Mist_pre_20160722
   ```

   Then restart Mist, add The DAO contract and check the balance.

   The process above does not remove your Ethereum accounts.

Comment: First of all, thank you!  1. I have checked, it is non-zero. 2. Done, still "0". 3. Done. 4.New contract still shows "0"

Comment: It is geting more interesting, after second reload of Mist- my Main Ether accounts now also shows "0", while an hour ago there was some ether and I have not done any transactions in a meantime..

Comment: Points 1-3 are ok. As it comes to p.4, blocks just started syncing all over again, there are approx 700k to sync, I'll let it sync, then I'll check following points and let you know. thanks!

Comment: I've just finished resyncing and finally my eth was visible. Then I went through all the withdrawal steps and everything worked just fine. Think you so much, you have solved my problem!