# If I backup my ethereum wallet, and then add to it, will the backed up copy have the funds in it?

Tags: backup

So if I follow this guide, 
[How to backup mist wallets?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets)

and backup my mist wallet, do I need to back it up again? Or will the backup contain all future funds?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes.**

Any copy of your wallet will have access to all ETH (or any other token) that it possesses. This is because wallets consist of *private keys* which identify the holder as the owner of a given address on the blockchain. As long as you have that key, you can access that address.