# Ethereum contracts problems sync appdata token (ETHEREUM WALLET)

Tags: contract-development

please help I have created contract and tokens with my account. After 2 days I couldn't sync and I deleted all my appdata and started resync. After it resynced I put my old keystore and my ether does show but my contract and "contract admin page" doesnt show. How do I restore this? Thank you

**UPDATE**
I am using Ethereum official wallet downloaded from www.ethereum.org

Comment: why down vote? o.O

Comment: I think someone down-voted this because you're not giving the tools you're using. Give more information like are you using Mist?

Comment: @Crema ok thanks, now is 2 downvotes :) you downvoted also? I will downvote two! so let make it -3 for nothing Thank you!

Comment: @ThomasFiedler Here you have some information about Ethereum Wallet/Mist backups (https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/946/how-to-backup-mist-wallets). They do not store contract information, you have to manualy add them again.

Comment: Also for the next time read this https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask so your question have the minimum information for it to be answered.

Comment: @ThomasFiedler I did not downvote, and I just upvoted now