# Ethereum Wallet access help needed

Tags: wallets, mist, public-key

**EDIT:** 
How can I gain access to Ethereum in the now discontinued Mist wallet ? 
I have a 42 characters code which I presume is the wallet number ? 
I have the password I used for the wallet.
I have a 66 characters code that shows as "Transaction Hash". 
The keystore information was destroyed.

Is this information enough to gain access to my ETH balance, or is it lost ?

Comment: What?Don't you know how to change your wallet? May God bless you

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you provide some more helpful information ?

Comment: The 42 characters might be the public address, and the 66 characters might be the private key or a transaction hash. If I'm not wrong Mist used .json files to store the encrypted private key.

Comment: @Ismael unfortunately I don't have the json files. I have a 66 characters code that shows as "Transaction Hash". so my question is  this information enough to gain access to my ETH balance, or is it lost ?

Comment: @c0der It is not possible to operate an Ethereum account without the private key to sign transactions. If you still have the Mist installation check this answer https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1981 to locate the json files.

Comment: @Ismael thank you for your answer. I know where the keystore should be. Long story but It is not available anymore. I only have the password, the public key and the "Transaction Hash".

Answer (score 2):

You could just use another wallet like metamask and give it your private key and password. Which wallet you use doesn't actually matter.

Comment: Please see my edit. Can I gain access to my ETH with the information I have ?

Answer (score 1):

You can download the MyCrypto app at download.mycrypto.com
You'll be able to enter your information and get in.

Your code and password is universal :)

Comment: Please see my edit. Can I gain access to my ETH with the information I have ?

Comment: Yep! Try using this https://support.mycrypto.com/how-to/migrating/moving-from-mist-to-mycrypto