# Can I test different OS and combine the keystore folder later?

Tags: accounts, backup, linux, import, windows

I have to move from Linux to Linux but also want to test under Windows. Is there any issue in running accounts and wallets under the different OS with a view to combining them under a single OS at a later date.

I know that if I run the geth console and type `admin.datadir`
I can see the full path and then export the blockchain in binary format with:

`geth export <filename>`

Then I can copy the blockchain_backup file to the new system and on the new system run:

`geth import <filename>`

I can see how to backup my accounts in the keystore folder [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts/)  and I've read the original [Backup/Restore instructions](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Backup-&-restore). **I'd like to be sure I have not missed anything** that may seem obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer

The short answer to your question is **yes** you can test your keys/wallets on different OS's.

---

### Important Note:

**KEEP MULTIPLE BACKUPS OF YOUR KEYS IN SECURE/SEPARATE PLACES**

---

### Other Comments

If you are intending to only use geth across your various OS's there shouldn't be an issue exporting and importing the keys as you have described. I made the first backup warning in bold because there is always a chance that keys can become corrupted or incorrectly copied as they are moved from computer to computer (or VM to VM). You can export the keys using the `export` command as you have described and/or copy/paste your keystore file from one PC to another.

If you decide in the future to use other Ethereum clients such as TurboEthereum (C++ client), EthereumJ, EthereumH, etc., be sure to keep up with how each client handles imports, exports, and formats of the keys. [Here is a good guide on using `ethkey`](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/ethkey.html) from the C++ team to help understand and export/import Ethereum keys.

Finally, keep in mind that you need to very securely scrub your hard drive of your key data if you no longer intend to use the particular OS's storage for that key. If you have your keystore on multiple computers that raises the risk of someone obtaining your keystore and trying to break into your wallet.

Comment: ok, good to know, will read up and around and test ... thanks