# Is the address under the Ethbase account in mist a public address?

Tags: mist, private-key, keymanagement, public-key

Is the address under the Ethbase account in mist a public address?

If so, how do I find the related private key?

Comment: It depends, which client runs behind your mist? geth?

Comment: Well I stopped geth, as I read that Mist has/acts as integrated node . Did I understand correctly ? Version 0.3.9 (0.36.4)

Comment: I think it may be correct because the following gives errors : geth --fast
I0210 14:25:58.932718   10870 database.go:71] Alloted 16MB cache to /Users/id/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
Fatal: blockchain db err: resource temporarily unavailable (check if another instance of geth is already running with the same data directory '/Users/id/Library/Ethereum')

Comment: please update your question with all the details, this will help users to answer quickly.

Comment: What details ?Using Mist 0.3.9 ... on the main screen we see an ethbase wallet/account. There is a key and there is an address/account ... is this a private or public address ? If not public were can I find the associated public address ? Am I correct in assuming that Mist runs a node as stated in the readme

Comment: Sorry, I presume you meant the question in the title which you updated ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all of the addresses shown in Mist are public keys. The encrypted private keys are stored in the keystore folder

> Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
>   Mac: /Library/Ethereum/keystore
>   Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum

[Source](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/108/131)