# How can I find my `chaindata` folder?

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp, datadir

Someone referred me to the `chaindata` folder to troubleshoot a problem I am having with `Ethereum-Wallet`/`Mist`.  How can I find it?

Answer (score 27):

**geth** (used in the Ethereum Wallet) saves its internal states for the main network in the `chaindata` directory. You can find it in the:

- `~/.ethereum` on Linux
- `~/Library/Ethereum` on OS X
- `~/AppData/Roaming/Ethereum` on Windows

In these directories, there are:

- `chaindata`: production blockchain
- `testnet`: test blockchain
- `keystore`: your keys

Comment: For OSX there are two library folders. You will need to enable hidden folders to fine the `Library` referenced above which is found in `HD/Users/{your name}/Library` and is a hidden folder

Comment: To view hidden folders run this in terminal `defaults write com.apple.finder AppleShowAllFiles YES` then relaunch finder (option+control click finder icon and select relaunch)

Comment: On mac open finder and press Cmd+Shift+G then you can directly navigate to the path `~/Library/Ethereum`

Answer (score 3):

When you first launch `Ethereum-Wallet` it will show the splash screen.  Shortly after the splash screen will show a `LAUNCH APPLICTION` button.  Click this button to see the full UI.  If you are fully synced already it may skip straight to the full UI

[image]

Once that is open go to the `Accounts` menu > `Backup` sub-menu > `Accounts` menu-item.

[image]

The UI for your file explorer will differ by OS, but you should see a folder that contains folders like this, in particular it should contain a `chaindata` folder:

[image]

Side-note: While you are here you should backup the `keystore` folder.  Details about this can be found at [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts).  Be sure to save your passwords as well!

Comment: We also emphasize that for each file in `keystore`, you also need to backup your **passwords**, http://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts

Comment: Edited to link to that question and mention saving password.

Comment: How does this answer relates to the actual question? Surely one of those has been edited, I need to downvote in this case. #offtopic

Comment: The question was how do I find chaindata folder in must.  This is a direct answer to that.  I'm not sure why you believe it isn't?

Answer (score 2):

On Mac OSX or GNU Linux, simply open a terminal and search for your `chaindata` using the `find` commandline tool:

```
find ~ -type d -name 'chaindata'
```

Where the first parameter `~` tells to look into your `$HOME` directory and all subfolders. Type `d` is for directories only.

A possible result looks like that:

```
/home/user/.ethereum-dev-private-testnet/chaindata
/home/user/.ethereum-consensys-public-testnet/testnet/chaindata
/home/user/.ethereum-fast/chaindata
/home/user/.ethereum-ethdev-berlin-testnet/chaindata
/home/user/.ethereum/chaindata
```

As you can see, I have multiple blockchains on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

On an Ubuntu system in a terminal/ CLI you can use:

> ```
> locate chaindata
> ```