# Geth account list is blank and also ethereum keystore value is blank

Tags: go-ethereum, rinkeby, keystore

I am new to ethereum block-chain. I created a smart contract. I want to deploy it on test network(Rinkeby) with ethereum node(geth).I install geth on system.And connect with Rinkeby test network. Ethereum node(geth) connect successfully with Rinkeby.  One place I got stuck. When I attach  geth on second pane on terminal window with command **geth attach**.

In console I check my account list with **geth.accounts** so it is blank list.One thing I also mention I check in **.ethereum directory** in this **keyStore** directory also empty.

Why eth account list is blank??Where I am doing mistake.If is it possible I am doing mistake in **ethereum geth** installation??

Comment: Did you create any accounts to use on the test network after installing geth? And, have you tried using truffle, ganache or a local private network for testing before deploying to Rinkeby?

Comment: Yes I have created account to use test network.I also get funded from (https://faucet.rinkeby.io/) on requested account address.But **eth.getBalance** is 0 on geth console.Yes I successfully deploy smart contract on local private network(**ganache**) for testing.Then I tried to deploy smart contract on **Rinkeby test network**.

Comment: If you used geth to create the accounts did you specify the datadir parameter (eg, geth --datadir "your directory" account new) where you are storing the rinkeby chain data?

Comment: Yes when I connect **geth** node to **rinkeby network** so  I give 'ipc path' .I run command like this.(geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="personal,eth,network,web3,net" --ipcpath "/home/anupam/.ethereum/geth.ipc).Geth node connect successfully.I saw the applied path during connectivity.Where is my chain data and keystore folder is empty.I think there should be my accounts private key

Comment: I create rinkeby account by this command **geth --rinkeby  account new**.

Comment: Check this thread - https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6550/how-can-i-find-my-chaindata-folder. From the look of it you didn't specify a datadir parameter so it's probably in the default geth locations. The datadir parameter is different to the ipcpath parameter. Or you could run a search on your computer for directory names "chaindata" or "keystore"

Comment: Yes you are right.My rinkeby folder on default **/home/anupam/.ethereum**  location.

Comment: So,Is it wrong step??

Comment: It's normally good practice to specify the datadir parameter when setting up geth so you are sure where the data is being stored. If that directory contains your chaindata and keystore directories then your account files should be in keystore directory. When you run geth attach do it from that directory you found. You could move the directory to another location but you will need to include the datadir parameter when starting your node to it knows where the find data files and accounts.

Comment: Hi Machine-Uprising, Thanks for nice answering.Let me ask you one thing.When I run command eth.syncing so the starting block number value is this 1978003.While I check eth.blocknumber in get console so,it value is 0.Why this is happen??Please tell me where I am doing mistake here??