# Is there a way to recover ETH with Account Number and Password Only?

Tags: wallets, blocks

I have 1 ETH in an Ethereum Wallet. I would like to transfer it, but I am unable
to get the wallet functions to work due to another issue. (Mist not recognizing my 1 ETH) I know the wallet address and the password. Is there someway to recover the ETH, into another account or service somewhere?

Comment: going down in flames here. already lost one ETH like this, when geth crashed last time and took keys with it. This wallet is still up and showing 1 Eth. Mist will not allow me to post any contracts though. see my other unanswered questions

Comment: how do i restore my Ether wallet account? I have the PW, keys and file on a CD. And in so doing will I lose my tokens on the account?
'myetherwallet.com'
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the password isn't enough you need to to restore the KEYSTORE and then you could move to another wallet or a online service (like https://www.myetherwallet.com/#view-wallet-info).
keystore location :

```
Linux: ~/.ethereum/keystore
Mac: /Library/Ethereum/keystore
Windows: %APPDATA%/Ethereum
```

more detail :
[How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts)

Comment: that worked! Pending transaction, now showing up in coinbase.

Comment: @ubiquitousDave: Good thing you kept the actual wallet/keystore file: it's what you need in addition to the password.