# how often should the wallet be backed up?

Tags: backup

Is it enough to backup the wallet when it is created or should they be backed up every so often. I am guessing it should be enough to back up once for every account but do not know much about cryptocurrency and this technology and wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

backup your wallet just once, you need only to preserve the private keys '`keystore`' and also remember the **password** you've set.
read : [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts)

Comment: I ended here because the linked question misses the very point of this question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends upon the no. of accounts you create/use. Each account will have a unique private key stored in the `keystore` folder. So, if you are operating with a single account, you need to backup the corresponding private key only once. This key won't change over time.

But, if you keep on creating new accounts, new keys will be generated(one for each account) and the ideal solution is to backup the `keystore` folder every time you create an account so that the new key pertaining to that account will be safe. However, this is not operationally efficient. So, there are different types of backup. See [differential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_backup) and [incremental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_backup) backup.

Comment: I am guessing these keystore files are small in size, so it is not too bad to just back them up without worrying too much about differential/incremental backups.