# What data makes up an Ethereum "account"? How can I recover an "account"?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, recovery

(I don't know if "account" is the right term. I suppose an Ethereum "account" is a certain kind of entry in the Ethereum blockchain.)

Suppose I create an "account" with [geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Managing-your-accounts): `geth account new`.

One day, the key files in `~/.ethereum/keystore` dissapear. Certantly, Ethereum accounts live on the Ethereum blockchain, **not** on my drive, so that doesn't mean my account has "died".

I have the following data:

1. The public key, aka. address
2. The ICAP
3. The "created key" (*What is the technical name for this?*)
4. The password I used to create the account with `geth`

Are these data sufficient to access my account?

If not, what additional data would I need?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest is to backup all key files **and each password** for every key file.

A key file is encrypted that's why the password is essential.

More information: [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts) and highly recommend that you test out the recovery process.

(For an advanced user, all that is needed is the [private key](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/10093/ethereum-private-keys)
because the public key, address, and ICAP can be derived from it.)

Comment: But if I don't have my private key, can I derive everything else just with the password, UUID ("created key"), and address?

Comment: No.  For more information see https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/15494/location-of-public-and-private-keys-of-ethereum-account