# Does use of geth removedb zero my account balance?

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, balances

Geth syncing is stuck for several hours. I want to delete my 
blockchain using `geth removedb`. Will this affect my account? Will my balance become zero?

Comment: The reason this _won't_ delete your account is because your balance, and everyone else's, is stored on each copy of the data that sits on each of the 25,000 nodes across the planet :)

Answer (score 2):

### No

As long as you control your private keys, your balance will not be affected.
You will see your full balance when the syncing is finished.

See [How do I backup my ether accounts?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/108/how-do-i-backup-my-ether-accounts)

Answer (score 1):

I did a geth removedb and synced from scratch. After sync was finished I checked my accounts balance and it was Zero. Before removedb it was ~3000.

and at the very end if u mine to nirvana your balance is in nirvana lost in infinite space- and the force is not with u anymore despite i like kurt cobains nirvana